# syntax error when trying to do an Eval

Tags: c#

i am trying to do this :

```
     <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SERIAL").ToString()!=""? %>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="Desc_lb" runat="server" visible="true">Desc</a>
        <telerik:RadToolTip ID="Description" runat="server" TargetControlID="Desc_lb" Text='Reference Order serial : <%#Eval("SERIAL") %>'></telerik:RadToolTip>
        <%# : "" %>
```

inside a repeater ItemTemplate but it's giving me a syntax error an invalid expression `:` and `syntax error : expected` near `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see and understand, try this, this is what you supposed to do:

```
<% if (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SERIAL").ToString() != "") { %>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="Desc_lb" runat="server" visible="true">Desc</a>
    <telerik:RadToolTip ID="Description" runat="server" TargetControlID="Desc_lb" Text='Reference Order serial : <%#Eval("SERIAL") %>'>
</telerik:RadToolTip><% } %>
```

Using short circuit is the problem

Comment: Container is not defined

Comment: Please post your complete code here, both `aspx` and the `cs` or `vb` file

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid syntax, you are trying to use expression ? true : false syntax and are not.

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SERIAL").ToString()!=""? %>
```

To fix it do a codebehind method and call it with the value returned from eval, like so.

```
<%# DoStuffWithSerial(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SERIAL"))) %>
```

Comment: Use regular `if - else` instead of `? :`

Answer (score 0):

thank you for you comment everyone but i find my solution and i fix it like this :

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="Desc_lb" runat="server" visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SERIAL").ToString()=="" %>'>Desc</a>
        <telerik:RadToolTip ID="Description" runat="server" TargetControlID="Desc_lb" Text='<%# "Reference Order serial :"+ DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SERIAL") %>'></telerik:RadToolTip>
```